# Getting cors error in pwa studio

Tags: magento2.3, pwa-studio

When I run the PWA studio project locally I get this error. And after an error in the browser console, it keeps sending requests to the server.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxx.com/Store/rest/V1/guest-carts' from origin
 'https://xxxx:8834' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
 to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
 header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs,
 set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

xxxx.com/Store/rest/V1/guest-carts:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: what webserver are you using? have you enabled cors there, by whitelisting your PWA URL?

Comment: I don't know about the backend server, I working on magento project first time. I am a react js developer.